# Finite construction of lacunary functions using algebraic and certain analytic operations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, singularity-theory

Algebraic functions have a discrete set of singularities. [Lacunary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function), e.g. $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$, have a continuum of singularities at every point of the boundary of their disk of convergence. The [Ostrowski–Hadamard gap theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski-Hadamard_gap_theorem) gives a sufficient condition for the exponents with non-vanishing coefficients for a power series which defines a lacunary function.

Can one also construct a lacunary function using only a finite number of algebraic operations, i.e. arithmetics and solving plane algebraic equations over the complex numbers, and a finite number of analytic operations, particularly applications of the exponential function and the logarithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have to define what a "lacunary function" means. There are various lacunary conditions in the literature.
2. If you mean sufficiently large lacunas so that your series have a whole circle of
   singularities, like in the example you give, such functions cannot be constructed as
   a finite composition of algebraic, exponential, and logarithmic ones.

One reason for this is the "Iversen property". Which is the following. Let $(f,z_0)$
be a germ of an analytic function. If for every curve $\gamma(t)$ 
starting at $z_0$, and 
every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a curve $\gamma'(t)$ starting at $z_0$ such that $|\gamma(t)-\gamma'(t)|<\epsilon$ for all $t$, and $(f,z_0)$ has an analytic continuation
along $\gamma'$, we say that $f$ has the Iversen property.

Composition of functions with this property also has it. Algebraic, entire and log functions have it. But a function with a whole line of singularities, evidently does not have it.